# Sending file using Spring Batch sftp

Tags: spring, sftp, spring-batch, spring-integration

I'm trying to send a file with sftp using Spring Batch.

I find a great example/tutorial on this site https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/09/send-data-secure-with-sftp-and-spring-batch/ which I followed, though I am getting the "Could not send file per SFTP: ..." caught exception in the example in the link above in the SftpTasklet class. I believe my problem is that the `int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter` in my application context is never getting called. The id associated with it `sftpOutboundAdapter` not referenced anywhere else on the page and I do not see how it gets called. I have found similar tutorials on other sites where it is also never explicitly called.

Basically, my question comes down to: how does the spring batch `int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter` get called?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tasklet sends a message (with a `File` payload) to `outputChannel` (`sftpChannel.send(message);`) which, in turn sends it to the outbound adapter.

Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` to see the messasge flow.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize that it was called implicitly. Appreciate your help.